# reference to container in DisplayTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a viewmodel class:

```
public class OrderLine {
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceExVat { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceIncVat { get; set; }
}
```

I have defined a custom DisplayTemplate Currency.cshtml to format currencies.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.PriceExVat, "Currency")
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.PriceIncVat, "Currency")
```

Currency.cshtml

```
@model decimal?
@Model.ToString() // here I need a reference to container to get the CurrencyCode
```

I know I can use the additionalViewData to pass a reference to container object into the display template:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.PriceIncVat, "Currency", new { conatiner = Model })
```

I was just wondering if it is already available inside the template. From the ModelMetadata I can only get the ContainerType.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this your best option is to create a custom class:

```
public class Currency {
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then for `OrderLine`:

```
public class OrderLine {
    public Currency PriceExVat { get; set; }
    public Currency PriceIncVat { get; set; }
}
```

In your `DisplayFor` call you can drop the extra param, as it will use the type name:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.PriceExVat
```

Then in **currency.cshtml** in the **DisplayTemplates** folder:

```
@model Currency
@(CurrencyCode): @Amount
```

Something like that will give you what you want I believe.

Comment: Just a note, `Currency` would probably work best as a `struct` so it functions kind of like a standard `decimal`, not sure if you could adapt `CurrencyCode` to be an `enum` or something so it could have a default value.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I have tried something similar, by using Money Type for the CLR (found it on Codeplex). But the code becoming more complex to write and maintain. I had to use the constructors  everywhere to initialize the structs, exceptions when trying to add values with different currencies etc. I think i'll just use additionalViewData to pass the container reference into the DisplayTemplate.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately no access to parent context unless that parent happens to actually be an action, the `ViewData` (and `Model`) instances are rebuilt when the template is invoked, so that's your only other option.